# AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

При запуске выдаётся ошибка: AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'rect'

```
import pygame, controls
from gun import Gun
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run():

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Space rangers')
    bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
    gun = Gun(screen)
    bullets = Group()
    inos = Group()
    controls.create_army(screen, inos)

    while True:
        controls.events(screen, gun, bullets)
        gun.update_gun()
        bullets.update()
        controls.update(bg_color, screen, gun, inos, bullets)
        controls.update_bullets(inos, bullets)
        controls.update_inos(inos)

run()
```

Жалуется на этот кусок:

```
def update_bullets(inos, bullets):
    # обновление позиций пуль
    for bullets in bullets.copy():
        if bullets.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullets)
    collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullets, inos, True, True)
```

Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Где-то я этот код уже видел, и даже подсказки по нему помню давал. У вас тут `bullets` - это одновременно и исходный список и элемент списка, перебираемый через `for`. Я подчеркнул проблемные места:

```
    for bullets in bullets.copy():
        ^^^^^^^
        if bullets.rect.bottom <= 0:
           ^^^^^^^
            bullets.remove(bullets)
                           ^^^^^^^
```

В цикле используйте `bullet` при обращении к отдельному элементу списка, а не `bullets`, который является списком этих `bullet`:

```
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Ещё по невнимательности было прописано spritecollide вместо groupcollide и теперь всё работает.

Comment: Я там несколько раз код подредактировал в процессе написания ответа, ну раз работает, то и хорошо :)